# Select all tr except last and first ones with .on()

Tags: jquery

Well i have a function that modify the tbody on the fly.
So i need to use something like this in 1.7.1:

```
$("table#id").on('click', 'tr', callback);
```

Now i need to get out of this event trigger the first and the last td.

So i do something like:

```
$("table#id").on('click', 'td:not(:first, :last)', callback);
```

But this doesn't work.
I tried with .live() too, and i don't get any result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) and [:last](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) match the first and last element *in the jQuery object*. Since you're using `on()`, that selector will be evaluated in the context of a jQuery object containing a single element (the event target). Therefore, that element will never be matched, as it is both the first and last item in the set.

Contrast [:first-child](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) and [:last-child](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/), which match the first and last element *in the parent element*. Using them should solve your problem:

```
$("#id").on("click", "td:not(:first-child, :last-child)", callback);
```

Comment: The worst thing is.. i'm using these selectors in the css but i dont realize of using them on jquery -.- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want the `:first-child` and `:last-child` selectors -- `:first` and `:last` are the last *matched elements*:

```
$('table').on('click', 'td:not(:first-child, :last-child)', function() {
    alert('hi');
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `first-child` and `last-child`selectors.
See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7pa9/).